# Why the FindFirstFile/FindNextFile does not list the entire content of the system directory on Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, delphi-xe3

I have a little question. The API `FindNextFile` does not list the entire contents of the directory `C:\Windows\System32` (Windows 7 only). Anyone have any solution?

Code [Delphi]:

```
Var
  sAtr:       String;
  sPathName:  String;
  I:          Integer;
  iCont:      Integer;
  tHnd:       THandle;
  tArrAtr:    TStringList;
  tWDF:       WIN32_FIND_DATA;
Begin
  iCont := 0;
  sAtr := '';
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  tArrAtr := TStringList.Create;
  tHnd := FindFirstFile(PChar(sPath + '*.*'), tWDF);

  If RightStr(sPath, 1) <> '\' Then
    sPath := sPath + '\';

  If tHnd = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
    Exit;

  Repeat
    If (tWDF.dwFileAttributes And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE) > 0 Then
      If (String(tWDF.cFileName[0]) <> '.') Then
      Begin
        sPathName := sPath + String(tWDF.cFileName);

        Result.Add(String(tWDF.cFileName) + sDel +
                   GetFileSizeAPI(sPathName));
        sAtr := '';
        Inc(iCont);
      End;
  Until (FindNextFile(tHnd, tWDF) <> True);

  //CloseHandle(tHnd);
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`?

Comment: I think your problem is similar to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155010/findfirstfile-findnextfile-recursive-search-not-finding-program-files

Comment: Why don't you use Delphi translation of this Windows API ?

Comment: `String(tWDF.cFileName[0]) <> '.')` isn't a very good check. File names can start with a `.` (like `.htaccess`) even though the Windows Explorer shell won't let you type such a name.

Comment: What files isn't it finding? Is there a pattern? For example is it missing all the hidden files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bet that you have a 64 bit machine and a 32 bit process. The [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) comes in to play and `System32` redirects to `SysWOW64`.

The best way to avoid the redirector is to execute a 64 bit process. Or you could list `Sysnative` to get the 64 bit system folder from a 32 bit process. You can even disable the File System Redirector but that is quite a dangerous thing to do and I would not recommend it.

Also, you tidy up the find handle by calling `FindClose` rather than `CloseHandle`. You should be adding the backslash before calling `FindFirstFile`. And test for special `.` and `..` by comparing the full name against those special values.